# What are the differences between "The light is blinking" and "The light is twinkling"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, phrase-choice

> [twinkle](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/twinkle_1?q=twinkle) ​[intransitive] to shine with a light that keeps changing
>   from bright to pale to bright again
>
> Stars twinkled in the sky.
>
> twinkling lights in the distance

---

> [blink](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blink_1?q=blink) ​[intransitive] to shine with an unsteady light; to flash
>   on and off
>
> Suddenly a warning light blinked.

---

What are the differences between "**The light is blinking**" and "**The light is twinkling**"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Blinking" is a very specific on-off sequence. A blinking light goes on, and then off repeatedly, like the turning indicator on a vehicle. A similar word is "flashing".

"Twinkling" is different. It is something normally said about the light from stars, rather than artificial lights. The dictionary says "*shining with a gleam that changes from bright to faint*". If you look at a star, it never goes *off*, but the light we see from stars rapidly changes due to atmospheric conditions.

A similar word is "flickering" - this is used to describe the flame of a fire, but also the random fluctuation in any kind of light, such as when an artificial light is beginning to fail.